# How to use WIX to deploy and run WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, installation, service, wix

I am trying to make an installer which deploys my wcf service, at the moment it is creating the virtual directory, but when I try connect my app to it, I get a

> CommunicationException was unhandled
>   by user code The remote server
>   returned an error: NotFound.

I notice that if I create a virtual directory manually that it will connect and work, so I'm assuming IIS is doing something behind my back which is making it work.

This is the code I am using to create the virtual directory,please note this is inside a iis:WebSite tag if more information is needed please let me know.

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VAWebService" Directory="VAWebService" Alias="VAWebService">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="VAWebService" Name="VAWebService" 
         AllowSessions="yes" WebAppPool="VA_AppPool" />
    <iis:WebDirProperties Id="MyWebSite_Properties" AnonymousAccess="yes" 
         WindowsAuthentication="no" DefaultDocuments="service1.svc" 
         AccessSSL="yes" AccessSSL128="yes" AccessSSLMapCert="yes" 
         AccessSSLNegotiateCert="yes"   AccessSSLRequireCert="yes"   
         Read="yes" Write="yes" Execute="yes" Script="yes" />
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```

Does any one know how to fix this? any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of ASP.NET is shown in the ASP.NET tab of the Web App properties when it is created by the installer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't need Write or Execute set to yes.  You probably don't need AccessSSLMapCert or AccessSSLNegotiateCert or AccessSSLRequireCert either, unless you are using client certificates to authenticate to the site.   Are you setting these when you configure the site using IIS?